# You don't have permission to access /{local} on this server even though allowed from all

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7, httpd, selinux

I'm trying to set up a local repository on my cluster
but when I try to access to the defined directory with

```
curl "http://$(hostname -f):80/local_HDP/"
```

, the error messages shown

```
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /local_HDP/
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

local_HDP located in /root/local_HDP
I moved my repo contents within /var/www/html which is default Apache path and then set symbolic link with

```
ln -s /root/local_HDP local_HDP
```

but once I pointed to `curl "http://$(hostname -f):80/local_HDP/"`

and checked permissions with `ls -Z /var/www/html/`

```
lrwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 local_HDP -> /root/local_HDP
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 repos
```

apache own all, so why is still can't access to that directory
and Here're all the configuration from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/local_HDP">
    AllowOverride None
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

also disable SElinux

any suggestions ?
Thank you in advanced